# How to make Pycharm's debugger output fuller?

Tags: python, pandas, debugging, pycharm, ide

I remember good old days, when I used to debug matlab. Even when I had a massive array or table, when I wanted it to appear in the debugger's console, I got the entire array.

Now in Pycharm (Python) when I debug a program that involves pandas dataframes, when I ask debugger to display a big dataframe, all I get is mere two columns, even though there's plenty of space (screenshot below).
[image]

I'm not sure where to ask this question, because maybe it pertains to "advanced usage of pycharm" (good for SuperUser), or maybe it's just a matter of some pandas settings (stack overflow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These parameters may help:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
```